# Is my number not good enough?

Tags: php

*Excuse the tardy title.*

This question is related to `variable by reference`.

---

Lets say we have a little `for` loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $r = 15;
    $t = &$i + $r;
    array_push($a, $t);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 19
)
```

Returned output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

Yet if I have something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

    $r = 15;
    $num = &$i;
    $t = $num + $r;

    array_push($a, $t);
}
```

It returns the exact expected result as above.

Could somebody please shed some light on this.

Comment: What exactly is `$t = &$i + $r;` supposed to do?! The answer is *something something reference shenanigans something something*, which anyone can figure out in detail if they're so inclined and have enough time. The *real* answer is *Why are you doing that in the first place?!*

Comment: @deceze It looks silly yes, I'm trying to figure out why the first example wouldn't work, while the second one does. This isn't being used in production or anything, it's here for me to gain a better understanding of the variable by reference.

Comment: FWIW I'd say undefined actions lead to undefined results. I couldn't even explain what this line is *supposed* to do, so I'm not worrying about it not doing it... ;P

Comment: @deceze Haha okay you win this. It just intrigued me as to why they work/don't work. I mean they essentially do the same thing. (*Only difference being instantiating another variable (`$num`) in the second example?*)

Comment: Looks like PHP optimizer applies assignment operator and ignores ` + $r` part in such cases. You can check generated opcode and see produced "intermediate language".

Comment: Why do you want the reference there? Is it a bad example or a bad decision?

Comment: @Veda If you read the comments, where I stated `"it's here for me to gain a better understanding of the variable by reference"`.

Comment: @Phantom I guess so as well. Is there a way to prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have a go...

In the second example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {    
    $r = 15;
    $num = &$i;      // now $num and $i are the same thing - perfectly legitimate
    $t = $num + $r;  // equivalent to $t = $i + $r    
    array_push($a, $t);
}
```

Whereas in the first example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $r = 15;
    $t = &$i + $r;   // $t and $i are the same thing. $r is not involved
    $t = &$i * "anything you want"; // this does exactly the same thing        
    array_push($a, $t);
}
```

Note that [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php), these kinds of assignments are written like `$t =& $i`, which I think is a useful reminder that you're just creating an alias between **two** things and anything else in the same statement is irrelevant.

Comment: I'll accept that! You've explained it perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Darren no problem, thanks for accepting my answer. I removed the section about grouping the statement using parentheses as I don't think it added anything. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @TomFenech Can we say: $t and $i have the same address in the memory, and because of that they have the same value.

Comment: @MAZux I think that instead of thinking about memory addresses, you should just consider `$i` as an alias (another name) for `$t`. [References in PHP aren't actually memory addresses](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php).